# How would Newton explain mirages?

Tags: optics, conservation-laws, refraction, geometric-optics

Suppose we think of light as photon packets with tiny momentum, then with this picture in mind, go and see the refraction of light in mirages:

[image]

We see that the packets of light photons must be continuously under a nature of force since it must change natural path direction. How would Newton have explained this force since he had no knowledge of wave theory?

Comment: The photon is a massless particle, so it can't be expected to follow Newton's second law.

Comment: How would Newton have figured you out tho @ThePhoton

Comment: Maybe a better fit for [HSM.SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/), since it's a question about a historical perspective on physics and not a question about our current understanding of physics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newton literally wrote the book on [Optics](http://www.relativitycalculator.com/pdfs/Opticks_by_Sir_Isaac_Newton.pdf) and knew perfectly well how to predict refraction.

He did posit a speculation on the *reasons* for refraction - that is, light was composed of tiny, very subtle pieces which were subject to kinematic laws and had the tendency to accelerate towards regions of higher density, an interaction in which they exchanged some of their extremely small momentum with the medium subject to the 2nd Law. This speculation is mostly false, although it bears a trivial resemblance to quantum mechanics. However, the light does exchange momentum with the medium as it curves, subject to a revised 2nd Law,

$\frac {d}{dt} \vec P = \frac {d}{dt} (E\vec v/c^2)$

Note how the right hand side simplifies to  Newton's $ m\vec a$ for $v \ll c$ and constant $m\gt0$.

Comment: Does the change of direction enter the formula?

Comment: @PeterBernhard the above formula for momentum conservation will hold true for cases with changed direction, but it does not predict it on its own. It's just a restatement of Newton's 2nd law in a form that works for photons.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how photons are viewed. They are not moving particles in the Newtonian sense, and this has to do with the wave-particle duality of quantum theory. Light is absorbed by matter like a particle but propagates like a wave. Photons are the quanta of energy passed to matter. So refraction is an example of the wavelike nature of light, not the curved trajectories of light particles. It is interesting that Newton thought of light as literally particles, in the sense that you are implying here. But his conception differed greatly from the modern photon.

Comment: Would Newton have been able to explain redraction

Comment: Is my understanding correct: "light  propagates like a wave", and refraction is an example of this, whereas - and this I know from the Einstein episode "gravitation of the moon eclipsing the sun" - the gravitation of the earth is an example of "curved trajectories of light particles" (which are not an example for the wave-character of light).  Did I read you well?